# Flutter PDF editting

Tags: android, flutter, pdf-generation

I wanna create a flutter app that can fill the fillable form on PDF, what library that I supposed to use that's free and how? Some of the form will be filled with system's clock.

I tried to use pdftron and syncfusion but they are not free so whenever the trial ends, my app will not work.

Comment: Try ```pdf``` along with the ```printing``` package.

Answer (score 1):

You can use PDF dependency:

in pubspec.yaml add bellow dependency

```
dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      pdf: ^3.0.0
```

After that in your .dart page add below line

```
final pdf = pw.Document();
```

and

```
 pdf.addPage(
      pw.Page(
        build: (pw.Context context) {
          return pw.Center(
            child: pw.Text('This is a fillable PDF form'),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
pdf.save();
```

In return you can design what you want in pdf.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I'll try it immediately.